# SSL for Subdomains

Tags: iis, subdomain

We are using two different server to host website(WordPress - Linux) and Web Application(Sub Domains - IIS). We are using SSL Generated by LetsEncrpt for website and tried SSL brought from Godaddy. After Installing I'm facing **Common Name Invalid** and unable to proceed.

Website: [www.nextoramaps.com](http://www.nextoramaps.com) (Linux-WordPress)
Subdomains: [www.ccs.nextoramaps.com](http://www.ccs.nextoramaps.com) (Window - IIS)

Please suggest best to add SSL to both.

Comment: Your certificate for www.nextoramaps.com appears entirely valid. Your `www.css.nextoramaps.com` doesn't appear to exist; there's no DNS record, so Let's Encrypt won't be able to validate it.

Comment: We want to add subdomain in Godaddy but unable to do it. Its CCS not CSS

Comment: CCS or CSS, neither one exists. You need to fix the GoDaddy issue first; can't have Let's Encrypt SSL on a subdomain that doesn't exist.